# Qt files with git

Tags: git, qt, gitignore

I am writing a C++ application with Qt and using `git` for version control. I know that `Debug` and `Release` folders dont need to be pushed to my github repo because they are created by compilation.

My concerns are about Qt specific files. Which should be added to tracking and which can be ignored ? Can I safely ignore the entire `x64` folders or do they consist of something important which will be needed when somebody would like to run my app by pulling repo on another computer. And what about `.ui` files ?

Comment: I would ignore binary and compiled output

Comment: I usually do not push any output and avoid any binary files. The one that pulls a git repository should be able to build the project with minimal instructions (maybe on readme).

Comment: Add all (for the most part) the files that are needed to build the project.... whatever is created as part of the build process, ignore it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore+qt

Comment: See https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Qt.gitignore

Comment: .ui files should be in the source control.